# increment duplicate records based on a field

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have CSV File :

```
Notation    RFRange
 AA100      1000           
 AA100      1100         
 AA100      1200         
 AA100      1300
 AA100      1000
 BB100      1100
 BB100      1200
 BB100      500
 BB100      600
```

I want something like this

```
 Notation   RFRange   Mode
 AA100      1000      Mode1            
 AA100      1100      Mode1         
 AA100      1200      Mode1   
 AA100      1300      Mode1
 AA100      1000      Mode2  
 BB100      1100      Mode2
 BB100      1200      Mode2
 BB100      500       Mode1
 BB100      600       Mode1
```

**How should add Mode column and increment based on RFRange duplicate values?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are not a coding service. We can and will however help you if you are stuck. Please show us what you have tried and what help you need.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.cumcount()` with `.groupby()`.

```
df['Mode'] = df.groupby('RFRange').cumcount().replace(1, 'Mode2').replace(0,'Mode1')
df

Output:

    Notation    RFRange Mode
0   AA100       1000    Mode1
1   AA100       1100    Mode1
2   AA100       1200    Mode1
3   AA100       1300    Mode1
4   AA100       1000    Mode2
5   BB100       1100    Mode2
6   BB100       1200    Mode2
7   BB100       500     Mode1
8   BB100       600     Mode1
```